# Having trouble with knife tool

Tags: knife-tool

[image]

I am having an issue with the knife tool. I'm attempting to make a cut where the maroon line is in the above image, however, when i click the left mouse button, the line goes away, and no cut is made. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or need additional information, I appreciate it.

Comment: Are you pressing [Enter] or Double left clicking to close the cut?  The appropriate hotkeys are in the status bar below the 3D view window.

Comment: Bertmoog, I have actually. I have used the knife tool before, even on this project, but for some reason it isn't working on this face. It has worked across the other ones, just not this one... :/

Comment: Excuse me then, it's hard to guess what a person's level of expertise is.  Can you upload your blend file?  It's difficult to see the problem from a photograph.  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: My response wasn't intended to be hurtful, so sorry if you interpreted it that way. This is the blend file:   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3674" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3674/)

Comment: No no, I meant literally "pardon me".  I wasn't being sarcastic, sorry.  Many people ask questions on here and they all have varying levels of experience. It's hard to tell if you just haven't ever used it before, or if you're having a legitimate problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having the issue is because there's no face there to subdivide.
 Editing in *Solid Shading* often makes things like this difficult to see.  Faces will always have a little black dot in the center, though.

Go to edge selection, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click one of the edges surrounding the void then press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the face.

After that, the knife tool will work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh you're a life saver! Sorry about the confusion, and I appreciate your quick response!

Comment: You're very welcome